# How can I change this code so that when you enter localhost:9080/?say=hello, it outputs hello?

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm trying to output hello when I enter enter localhost:9080/?say=hello. But I have no idea how to do it

```
public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9080);
        Socket client = ss.accept();
        Scanner in =new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        // running infinite loop for getting
        // client request
        while (true){
            String s = in.nextLine();
            if (s==null || s.trim().length()==0)
                break;
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
        String document = "<html><body>Salem</body></html>";
        String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                "Server: YarServer/2009-09-09\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                "Content-Length: " + document.length() + "\r\n" +
                "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        out.println(response+document);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at rest, Spring boot directly gives the plug and play code with rest

Comment: Maybe you should read up on the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) when trying to implement a HTTP server from scratch?

Comment: Java has its own [`HttpServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) class. Don't use `ServerSocket` directly to implement HTTP manually.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is a school work so I will not give you a ready-made working solution, just some hint.

Simplifying a lot, the HTTP protocol exchanges text strings between a client and a server.  Your code already prints the strings that the browser sends to your server; take a look at the first line: it says

```
 GET /?say=hello HTTP/1.1
```

"GET" is an "[HTTP method](https://assertible.com/blog/7-http-methods-every-web-developer-should-know-and-how-to-test-them)", it is followed by the path of the server-side resource you requested (just a slash in this case) plus any request param (the part after the question mark) and the protocol version.

To perform a specific action for a specific path/param requested by the client, your code should examine the first line of text submitted by the browser (for example you should check for the presence of `/?say=hello`).

Furthermore, usuallly an HTTP server doesn't shut-down after the first request, so your code should contain another infinite loop to wait for another connection after having served the first one.  Your code should also `close()` the client socket after you have sent the response to the browser.

Comment: In the code of the app, the client will disconnect after the first request, as he sends `connection: close`

Comment: @Ferrybig: the client SHOULD disconnect.  See also https://serverfault.com/questions/790197/what-does-connection-close-mean-when-used-in-the-response-message